# Where to find the framework of Fabric and Crashlytics for firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics, google-fabric

I need to download manually the framework of `Fabric` and `Crashlytics` for firebase. where I can download it ? on https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started they offer to use cocoaPods but i m not on Xcode so i need a link to download the .zip file to manually install it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a collapsed "Add frameworks manually" link right below the pod instructions on that page.

1. Download the [Crashlytics SDK files](https://storage.googleapis.com/firebase-preview-drop/ios/crashlytics/com.crashlytics.ios-manual.zip).
2. Unzip the files, and drag Crashlytics.framework and Fabric.framework to your project's Project navigator.
3. Check Copy items if necessary if it isn't already checked, then click Finish.

Comment: As of today, there is no "Add frameworks manually" link on the get-started page.

Comment: @KellySetzer I still see it there about halfway down the page after the third code sample as of this morning.   Right above Step 3: Initialize Crashlytics

Comment: I wish I could edit or flag my own post.  All I can do is delete it, which seems like a shame because your response is valuable.  The link is easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

On this page, you'll also find a link that they're pointing to:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

> 1. Download the **framework SDK zip**. This is a ~200MB file and might take
>    some time to download.

Currently it points to:
https://firebase.google.com/download/ios